# How to instantiate a specific number of items in a dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm trying to declare a `Dictionary<Task>` with a specific number of items, I tried:

```
private Dictionary<Task, CancellationToken> bots = 
        new Dictionary<Task, CancellationToken>(new Task[9], new CancellationToken[9]);
```

this will return the following error:

> you can not convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task []' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary '

all works if I do this in a `List`:

```
private List<Task> bots = new List<Task>(new Task[9]);
```

Comment: Your example are totally different. You need to create a dictionary object, typically a `KeyValuePair`. right now you are trying to pass 2 object type

Comment: That won't work, because all of the keys would be the same!

Comment: I suspect this, unfortunately is not what I'm looking for, thanks anyway

Comment: Amy is right, this doesn't make  sense. All the keys would be `null` and even one is not allowed

Comment: Note, if you were expecting actual `Task` and `CancellationToken` objects to appear: that won't happen even with your `List` example, because `new Task[9]` allocates **an array of 9 entries** which are **all null** (*not initialized*). Even if the Dictionary code worked, it would try to create 9 `null`-keys which is not allowed.

Comment: @JuveMerda, I've also added example if tasks and cancellationTokens are already filled(populated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error shows you're trying something that doesn't exists.

One of the override Dictionary constructor accepts

```
public Dictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary);
public Dictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer);
```

And neither of the parameters you gave is correct.
The 1st input you gave is Task[] and the 2nd is CancellationToken[]

You should create a IDictionary implementation which is usually a Dictionary and then passing it to it.

```
var example1Original = new Dictionary<Task, CancellationToken>();
example1Original.Add(new Task(DoWork), new CancellationToken());
example1Original.Add(new Task(DoWork), new CancellationToken());
// and more (This procedure can be shorten using a loop)

var example1Result = new Dictionary<Task, CancellationToken>(example1Original);
```

As you can see, we successfully passed our variable into the Dictionary constructor, this is possible because Dictionary implements IDictionary as we can see here
[image: Declaration of Dictionary<TKey, TValue>]

But the last line is actually redundant, because yes we can pass it, but we don't need to. Because our populated example1Original is already a Dictionary which is what we're aiming to.

So it begs the question, why the Dictionary constructor has it in the first place. Which leads us to our original statement, that IDictionary can have multi implementations which can be passed.

Here are few of IDictionary implementations
[image: IDictionary<TKey, TValue> implementations]
(Picture taken from mscorlib.dll using ILSpy)

So your question is actually, how can i populate my Dictionary with a new instances of Task and Cancellation tokens.

This can be done with:

1. Previous above code. (And shorten more by a loop)
2. Or using a nice language capability in a shorter manner.

Capabilities we're going to use

- System.Linq.Enumerable.Range - Generates a sequence of integral numbers within a specified range.
- System.Linq.Enumerable.Select - Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.
- The power of Interfaces - For allowing us to use the ToDictionary extension method.
- System.Linq.Enumrable.ToDictionary() - Extension method that takes IEnumerable and generates a Dictionary

Enumerable.ToDictionary - Because IDictionary itself implements IEnumerable we can then use the following ToDictionary extension method

Extension method from *System.Linq* namespace

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TElement> ToDictionary<TSource, TKey, TElement>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector);
```

If we will use those capabilities we can build the following to generate our Dictionary.

```
var kvpOfTaskCancellation = Enumerable.Range(0, 9) // Generates Enumerable integers sequence.
    .Select(i => new KeyValuePair<Task, CancellationToken>(new Task(DoWork), new CancellationToken())) // Iterating and projecting every elements inside the previous generated sequence.
    .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value); // Mapping each iteration from the previous line KeyValuePair objects to the Dictionary Key and Value.
```

Which can also be shorten to the following

```
var kvpOfTaskCancellation2 = Enumerable.Range(0, 9)
    .ToDictionary(kvp => new Task(DoWork), kvp => new CancellationToken());
```

This all works if you want a new Task and Cancellation token.

**But** if you already have a filled collection of Tasks and CancellationTokens and you want to generate from them a Dictionary, then you can do the following:

```
var tasks = new Task[3];
// I'm assuming the tasks already been populated
tasks.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp, kvp => new CancellationToken());
```

But if you also have a CancellationToken array as well, then you can use the following:

```
var tasks = new Task[3];
var cancellationsTokens = new CancellationToken[9];
// I'm assuming tasks and cancellationToken array already been filled.
Enumerable.Range(0, tasks.Length)
    .Select(i => new KeyValuePair<Task, CancellationToken>(tasks[i], cancellationsTokens[i]))
    .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

An uninitialized array of `Task` only contains null elements and you can not have null as the key of a dictionary item, but in general, if you have initialized arrays, you can have dictionaries with those arrays using Linq:

```
var dictionary = (from token in new CancellationToken[9]
                 from task in initializedTaskArray
                 select (task, token)
                 )
                 .ToDictionary(x => x.task, x => x.token);
```

Answer (score -2):

You would need to do something like the following:

```
private Dictionary<Task, CancellationToken> bots = new Dictionary<Task, CancellationToken>() {
    { new Task(), new CancellationToken() },
    { new Task(), new CancellationToken() },
    ...
}
```

Comment: As a note for the OP, notice the brackets enclosing the `Task` and `CancellationToken` object. This is to separate the definition to tell the compiler that the left part is the `Key` and the right part is the `Value`. This answer is the short version. A longer one using `KeyValuePair` is also possible.

Comment: @Eric-Magers You can not compile your code because of `Task()` class has [no default constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: @yW0k5o I do not know what the OP's intent is for the task so there's no point in me trying to come up with a random action to put in there

Comment: @EricMagers If the question doesn't contain enough information for it to be answered then the solution is to flag the question for the corresponding reason, not to post an answer that doesn't actually work and use the unanswerability of the question as a shield for criticism.

Comment: @Servy The question wasn't how to create a task, it was how to create a dictionary with a set of Tasks and Cancellation tokens. There was enough information to answer that. If the OP was asking how to create a Task to perform some task then I would agree.

Comment: @EricMagers The question was how to create a dictionary having a set number of items without actually adding the items.  You haven't done that.   You haven't even posted code that *compiles* either.